# How to make generic class global in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How to make `Hash` globally available?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUGMA2BDAzruACTwAsAeAaQBo4A1APkRVRQBNgtspg4BzTCACNsmJnDgB6CXAD8c5mgDuASwB2rCIoB0xXCTgBeIqUnSAouAi41vOMvj8hIzAE8gA)

```
export {}

class Hash<K, V> {
}

declare global {
  // ???
}

window.Hash = Hash // Exposing it globally
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export {}

class Hash<K, V> {
}

type HashClassType = typeof Hash;

declare global {
  // dunno if there is a more preferable syntax but I think this works
  var Hash: HashClassType;
}

window.Hash = Hash // Exposing it globally
```